# ViewController.swift cannot be seen upon accessing Automatic in xcode assistant

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I just started with iOS Development in Swift, and I am facing a small issue. In Xcode assistant, when I select Automatic I cannot see the option `viewcontroller.swift`, it rather shows `viewcontroller.h`. Would be great if someone has any idea how to see `viewcontroller.swift` upon select Automatic in Xcode asistant.

Comment: Update screenshot if possible

Comment: A screenshot would be nice.